# stuck on this elementary set theory problem

Tags: elementary-set-theory

State whether True or False:

For any three sets $A,$ $B,$ $C$ in a universal set $U$ , $(A\setminus B)\times C = A\setminus (B\times C)$.

My attempt : 
Let $A = \{1, 2, 3\} , B = \{3, 4\}$ and $C = \{4, 5\}$

$A\setminus B = \{1, 2\}$

Now $(A\setminus B)\times C = \{ (1,4), (1,5), (2,4), (2,5), (3,4) (3,5)\} .......1$

Also $B\times C = \{(3,4), (3,5), (4,4), (4,5)\}$

Now $A\setminus (B\times C) = \{ 1, 2, 3\} ....2$

Now $1 \neq 2$

So we can say that the statement is false.

I think I'm doing something wrong here. Kindly point the mistake so that I can correct it and learn from it.

Note: $A\setminus B$ represents the set of elements of $A$ that are not in$B$

Comment: You've put too many elements in $(A\setminus B)\times C$ but that doesn't matter for your counterexample. It looks good to me.

Comment: @DanRust is there a better way to prove this statement as false

Comment: @DanRust But I think I have evaluated $(A\setminus B)\times C$ correctly.

Comment: $3\notin A\setminus B$ so there should be no pairs $(3,x)$ in $(A\setminus B)\times C$. Generally, a counterexample is the easiest way to prove that a statement is false. There may be a smaller counterexample in your case, but that's about it. (Try $A=\{1\}, B=\emptyset, C=\emptyset$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution proves the point, though you could use smaller sets $A,B$ and $C$. However in your case $(A\setminus B)\times C = \{(1,4),(1,5),(2,4),(2,5)\}$ and nothing more, since $3 \in B$ thus $3\notin A\setminus B$.

In a more general context we can notice that $(A\setminus B) \times C$ will contain pairs of elements from A and $C$ while $A\setminus (B\times C)$ will contain elements in $A$. As pairs of elements are distinct from the elements themselves, these two sets will never be equal. With the exception if $A=\emptyset$, in which case both sides will equal $\emptyset$. On the other hand if $C=\emptyset$  then $(A\setminus B) \times C=\emptyset$ while $B\times C=\emptyset$ thus $A\setminus (B\times C)= A$ in other words  $$(A\setminus B) \times C\neq A\setminus (B\times C)$$
still hold.

Comment: What if $C = \emptyset$ is an empty set? I think the LHS will be $\emptyset$ and RHS will be equal to $A$.

Comment: I have updated the answer to also adress this case @user109256 .

Comment: I was correct about $C = \emptyset$.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out. I have now understood the concept.